# C# Long Switch Statements

Tags: c#

I've seen the articles on StackOverflow regarding c++ long switch statements, but c# is different in this regard.

Specifically, I would like to replace a hugely-long switch statement in c# code, where each case statement does the same thing, just the field name changes.

The code looks like this:

```
 case Fields.TRANSMITTERCONTACTPHONEEXT:
                {
                    int lengthNeeded = 0;
                    int currentLength = TransmitterContactTelephoneExtension.Length;
                    int lengthRequired = TransmitterContactTelephoneExtensionLength;
                    if (currentLength < lengthRequired)
                    {
                        lengthNeeded = lengthRequired - currentLength;
                        for (int i = 0; i < lengthNeeded; i++)
                        {
                            TransmitterContactTelephoneExtension += " ";
                        }
                    }
                } break;
            case Fields.TRANSMITTERFEIN:
                {
                    int lengthNeeded = 0;
                    int currentLength = TransmitterFEIN.Length;
                    int lengthRequired = TransmitterFEINLength;
                    if (currentLength < lengthRequired)
                    {
                        lengthNeeded = lengthRequired - currentLength;
                        for (int i = 0; i < lengthNeeded; i++)
                        {
                            TransmitterFEIN += " ";
                        }
                    }
                } break;
```

I'd like to just get this down to a single function that can figure out which field I mean without having to use a switch statement. Is there a way to pass in a variable containing the field name?

Comment: you will need to provide more code then that... show your whole class, or method, at least

Comment: @TaW - Switch is beautiful, when used appropriately.

Comment: Having non-functional `breaks` in it, it is anything but beautiful. And being restricted to integers makes it a poor language construct. Lagacy in the worst meaning of the word, coming from a century when saving a jump was considered more important than creating structured code.

Comment: So, @TaW, is switch like 'goto' ?

Comment: Um, no. Goto is simple and simply necessary in some (rare) situations. It can be abused, sure. But `switch` is simply a terribly ugly construct; of course only explicable from the historic perspective. But still awful and a missed chance to improve on C..

Comment: @TaW - switch in c# (the language for this post) is not limited to integers.  it can also use bools, strings, chars, enums.  The breaks are, in a way, just closing brackets for the cases.  When you have a long list of if.... elseif...elseif....elseif, it is often a much more readable and equally well structured method to just use a switch statement.  It's surprising that you would think switch evil but goto, the statement most responsible for spaghetti code, to be "simple and ... necessary".

Comment: The problem nr one is that in order to use it you need to convert the real expressions from the problem domain to somethingd that evaluates to integer. (The original C/C++ version was even worse, luring folks to change the logical order to something else in order to use of fall-through to save a jump instruction. Arrgh..) -  The other problem is that you are misquoting me to make a wrong .point. Read my comment agian, it is only a few lines to the top! If you never encountered one of these __rare__ cases, don't worry. I come across one or two per year.. Switch? Never.

Comment: In the last 20 years of programming, the only time I had to convert a switch expression was back when strings were not allowed.  With c# allowing strings, that is gone.  With c# allowing other integer related types, like enum, readability gets right down excellent.  And again, no need to convert.  And I did not misquote you to make a wrong point. Even allowing for *rare* situations, it is still surprising how you accept goto as "simply necessary" while putting down switch as "simply a terribly ugly" and "evil" construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all the changeable values into arrays and index into it. Make sure the enum int values are the same as the data in the target arrays.

```
var current = (int) Fields.TRANSMITTERCONTACTPHONEEXT;

int lengthNeeded = 0;
int currentLength = LengthData[ current ] ;
int lengthRequired = RequiredData[current ];

if (currentLength < lengthRequired)
{
      lengthNeeded = lengthRequired - currentLength;
      for (int i = 0; i < lengthNeeded; i++)
      {
         Extensions[ current ] = Extensions[ current ] + " ";
      }
}
```

---

This post looks at the *pattern* of the operations in the switch and does not address any localized deficiencies of individual operations. Please look at each of the individual operations and where needed improve it for optimal operational efficiencies.

Comment: So current is keeping track of which field I'm on. That would work well, and remove some of this code bloat. Thanks, OmegaMan!

Comment: @SuLlewellyn Yes exactly, it will reference into multiple arrays to get or set values as needed.

Comment: This means that your are going to have to assign each of your text fields and each of your needed length fields to each element in one or two arrays, and then assign the text fields back when you are done looping through the array and padding them.  In far less code, you can call the PadRight function for each field, and it will be far more readable.

Comment: @Gilchrist I wholeheartedly agree with your thoughts on using `PadRight`.The post answered *to the pattern* of the shown process and didn't look into the deficiencies of the individual operations.

Comment: Take note that [parallel collections are an anti-pattern](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) and should be avoided.

Comment: So, I ended this by creating a class called FieldNode that contains all the info about the field I need, including its length requirement and name. I can enumerate through the list of FieldNode objects and call PadRight to the length required. Then, I just pad all the fields in the record. It works!

Comment: @SuLlewellyn Nice. :-) Sounds like an OO solution.

Comment: SuLllewellyn and @OmegaMan. That really does not look like an OO solution.  The class should probably be something like Transmitter, and have member variables like ContactPhoneExt and FEIN.  Putting those member variables and lengths into arrays is moving the information into parallel collections (the arrays) which is what DavidSherret's referenced article is saying should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

This just looks like the code for a string pad function repeated multiple times.  You could just have

```
case Fields.TRANSMITTERCONTACTPHONEEXT:
     TransmitterContactTelephoneExtension = TransmitterContactTelephoneExtension.PadRight(TransmitterContactTelephoneExtensionLength, ' ');
     break;
    ...
```

Any time that you find yourself repeating code over and over, you probably can break it out into a separate function (if one does not already exist) and just call it with the right parameters.

And this also makes me wonder if you need the switch case statement at all, and not just a series of pad statements.  But that is going further out (in scope) in your code.  And your post does not give us enough info to go there.

Finally, somewhat applicable to your question, my rule of thumb (not originally mine, but I forget where I got it) is that if a method is more than a pageful (intentionally vague term), then I need to break it up into other separate methods.  That allows me to look at a method and understand it without scrolling around.  It also forces me to separate a longer process into smaller logical steps.

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to do is make a single function and call with the right parameters. It's just figuring out how to make a pointer to a field in c# I think that's messing me up.

Comment: @SuLlewellyn: Unfortunately, it's not possible to pass properties as `ref` parameters.

Comment: Oftentimes, you don't need to pass in a parameter by ref (pointer) to have the function modify it.  As in this case, your function can take the previous value, any additional parameters of interest, and return the update value.  Then you can say something like MyValue = MyValue.Fixit(paremeter1, parameter 2...).

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset - Thanks for the info!  Sometimes I miss old C++ for this kind of reason, (being unable to pass a pointer to a property), but I really like c#.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables in advance, and use the `switch` only for the assignments that differ:

```
int currentLength;
int lengthRequired;

switch (whatever) {
case Fields.TRANSMITTERCONTACTPHONEEXT:
    currentLength = TransmitterContactTelephoneExtension.Length;
    lengthRequired = TransmitterContactTelephoneExtensionLength;
    break;
case Fields.TRANSMITTERFEIN:
    currentLength = TransmitterFEIN.Length;
    lengthRequired = TransmitterFEINLength;
    break;
default:
    throw new Exception(); // Without this, the compiler will complain about uninitialized variables
}

int lengthNeeded = 0;
if (currentLength < lengthRequired)
{
    lengthNeeded = lengthRequired - currentLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthNeeded; i++)
    {
        TransmitterFEIN += " ";
    }
}

switch (whatever) {
case Fields.TRANSMITTERCONTACTPHONEEXT:
    TransmitterContactTelephoneExtension += " ";
    break;
case Fields.TRANSMITTERFEIN:
    TransmitterFEIN += " ";
    break;
}
```

Edit: OmegaMan's solution is way better if you have the option of replacing the variables with an array.

Comment: Very helpful. Plus, I wasn't aware of the default case issue.

Answer (score 0):

You really should break this out into a method. So that you are not duplicating code over and over. That is inefficient and can lead to potential errors when updating.

Also instead of looping you should make use of the PadRight() method on strings.

I would do this:

```
case Fields.TRANSMITTERCONTACTPHONEEXT:
     TransmitterContactTelephoneExtension = PadString(TransmitterContactTelephoneExtensionLength, TransmitterContactTelephoneExtension);
     break;
case Fields.TRANSMITTERFEIN:
     TransmitterFEIN = PadString(TransmitterFEINLength, TransmitterFEIN);
     break;


private string PadString(int requiredLen, string value)
{
     if (value == null) return String.Empty.PadRight(requiredLen, ' '); //Create an empty string when the value is null
     return value.PadRight(requiredLen, ' ');
}
```

Comment: The PadRight method is definitely something I need to be using. (Note: here is the MSDN article:

Comment: Link  https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.String.PadRight);k(PadRight);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like the code we can't see needs some refactoring, but based on what we can see, I would recommend doing the following:

```
// 1. Have a class to hold your data
class FieldData
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int LengthRequired { get; set; }

    public string RightPaddedValue
    {
        get { return Value.PadRight(LengthRequired, ' '); }
    }
}

// 2. Fill your data into a dictionary somehow... for example:
Dictionary<Fields, FieldData> fields = new Dictionary<Fields, FieldData>
{
    { 
        Fields.TRANSMITTERCONTACTPHONEEXT, 
        new FieldData {
            Value = TransmitterContactTelephoneExtension,
            LengthRequired = TransmitterContactTelephoneExtensionLength
        }
    },
    { 
        Fields.TRANSMITTERFEIN,
        new FieldData {
            Value = TransmitterFEIN,
            LengthRequired = TransmitterFEINLength
        }
    }
};

// 3. Then use the data from that dictionary in your code:
FieldData data = fields[selectedField];
data.RightPaddedValue; // use RightPaddedValue
```